# Pre selected options on form depending on the link you're coming from?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So, I have a day, month and year select options in the form. The page is called `new.php` and the page that's linking to it is `event.php?d=1&m=1&y=2015`.

Because it's coming from that link I want the selection options to be on the corresponding date (1st of January, 2015).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try something yourself first, show what you did and what went wrong

Comment: I literally have no idea how I would do this. I did the whole scheduling system and this is the last and final feature I'm stuck on.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (not reliable, sent by client) or $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] - ip

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $day = $_GET['d'];
    $month = $_GET['m'];
    $year = $_GET['y'];

    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . $month . $year));
?>

<input type="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>">
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work if the input field was a type date, it's actually 3 select boxes with options ( I know... )

Answer (score 0):

One way is to look at the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] variable and use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to parse the url nicely and get the query variables from there, and then use them as your value in the form element. But like Cox mentions in the comment it's a bit unreliable as it is set by the client.

Another way would be to set either one or 3 session variable on the event.php page like so:

```
$_SESSION['d'] = $_GET['d'];
$_SESSION['m'] = $_GET['m'];
$_SESSION['y'] = $_GET['y'];
```

Then in your new.php file you start use the session variables as the value in the form element. Don't forget to start the session on both pages with session_start().

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using client side scripting (I recommend jQuery) then you could get the select boxes showing the correct data.

Set three JavaScript variables based on the URL string variables.
Then on document ready use JavaScript/jQuery to set the select boxes to the JavaScript variables..

```
<?php
  $day = $_GET['d'];
  $month = $_GET['m'];
  $year = $_GET['y'];

  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "$(function() {";
  echo "$('#day').val(".$day.");"
  echo "$('#month').val(".$month.");"
  echo "$('#year').val(".$year.");"
  echo "});"
  echo "</script>"              
?>
```

Then have the select statements with an ID so that jQuery can update the correct elements within the DOM..

```
 <select id="day">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
 </select>
```

etc.. for the rest of the days, then the correct id for the month selector and also year selector.